# how to implement recaptcha in react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, recaptcha

I have used "npm install react-native-recaptcha-v3" for recaptcha integration. But it gives a warning Failed prop type: The prop 'url' is marked as required in 'ReCaptcha', but its value is 'undefined'. what was I do wrong?

how to resolve it?

```
     render() {
        return (
        <View>
        <ReCaptcha
          sitekey= {this.props.sitekey}
          verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback.bind(this)}
        />
       </View>
       );
      }
```

Comment: That package is for React, and React-Native uses different components. I don't think you can use it as-is. Try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-v3 (found by googling "react native recaptcha")

Comment: but it does not give description how to use.

Comment: It has a **Usage** section right on that same page. It of course assumes general knowledge about implementing recaptchas I guess.

Comment: This question is posting by me because, react native is new for me. and also javascript.

Comment: Well, not sure what to tell you. Stackoverflow isn't a how to site where other people write free tutorials for you. You need to learn how to use the things you want to use yourself and come back once you get stuck on a serious problem and have tried to solve it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking at `React.js` vs `React Native`.

`React.js` packages are not intended for `React Native`. Think of React Native as an extremely specific version of React.js because it is built specifically for mobile devices - specifically Android and iOS.

There are packages specific to React Native like [this one](https://github.com/acsant/react-native-recaptcha).

I would also think of the user experience and why you need a Recaptcha on a phone.

It's not exactly an ideal user experience as people get frustrated easily when they have bad connections and will give up.

Comment: this is an security  option for signup form. It will be benificial for avoid fake accounts. I tried to use which one you suggest but gives a warning  **Failed prop type: The prop 'url' is marked as required in 'ReCaptcha', but its value is 'undefined'.**   what was I do wrong?

Comment: @Sam009 It's really difficult to know what's happening without seeing your code. Can you update this post with the related code?

Comment: URL is a required prop: 

***url URL associated with the app (This is the domain url that you registered on Google Admin Console when getting a siteKey)***
Screenshot: https://screencast.com/t/O7e2W6vO

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReCaptcha
   siteKey={SiteKey}
   action="<action_name>" // it's not required but you can it if you are using recaptcha more than one time.
   url="<use_any_valid_url_or_app_related_url>"
   reCaptchaType={1}
   onExecute={(res) => {
      this.setState({ reCaptcha: res });
   }}
/>
```

> URL props is required for react-native-recaptcha-v3 so you can pass any valid URL or app related URL and make sure URL starts with something like 'https://stackoverflow.com/'. if you simply use 'stackoverflow.com' as URL it shows an error for URL.
>   As soon as from render onExecute() executes and in res variable, you got the recaptcha token, which you can use for verifying the recaptcha.
>   and one more point, there are no props like **verifyCallback** in react-native-recaptcha-v3. So don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

first create recaptcha keys at
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

then you create an new component like this:

```
const GetRecaptcha = (props) => {
const onMessage = (data) => {

    console.log('recaptcha', data.nativeEvent.data)
    //here you can put your action to perform(check validation on your server or somthing)
    props.action(data.nativeEvent.data);

};

return <View style={{}}>

    <WebView
        style={{height: 0}}
        onMessage={async (e) => await onMessage(e)}
        containerStyle={{height: 0}}
        source={{
            html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=RECAPTCHA-KEY"></script>
        <script>
        function onLoad(e) {
         
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('RECAPTCHA-KEY', {action: 'submit'}).then((token) => {
                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(token);
                });
            }) 
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="onLoad()">
        </body>
        </html>`
        , baseUrl: 'your-url',
    }}/>


</View>;
};
```

you could use this component from other component as this example:

```
const action=(token)=>{
   // validate key on server
   if(token){
    //do some action
   }else{
   //do some action
   }
  }
  const App=()=>{
  return <GetRecaptcha action={action}/>
  }
```